# Specific vector space isomorphism preserving a special range.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V = C^0
(\mathbb{R}$) be the vector space of continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R} $ (over $\mathbb{R}$).

$U1 := \{f ∈ V : f(x) = f(x + 1) \forall x ∈ R\}$

$U2 := \{f ∈ V : f(x) = −f(x + 1) \forall x ∈ R\}$

(b) Find a linear isomorphism $T : V → V$ such that $T(U_1) = U_2.$

**Question**: I just wanted to see if there was in fact such an isomorphism because I cannot seem to produce one. I have already tried the typical maps $T(f(x))=f(2x)$ and $T(f(x))=f(\frac{x}{2})-f(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2})$. Both of which don't satisfy the condition given in b.

Comment: You mean that they are not isomorphisms?

Comment: The map $T(f(x))=f(2x)$ doesn't satisfy the second condition. Namely, $T(U_1)=U_2$. To see this look at constant functions.

Comment: The map $T(f(x))=f(\frac{x}{2})-f(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2})$ isn't an isomorphism. Look at constant functions again.